# problema com "inspecionar elemento"

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Amigos;

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação e tenho um gerenciador onde listo os registros do banco de dados. As informações são dispostas em uma tabela
e tenho um checkbox para seleção dos registros que podem ser editados ou deletados. Dessa forma:

```
<input name="selecionados[]" id="110" class="iCheck" type="checkbox">
```

O id é a chave primaria do registro. O que me acontece é que se eu modificar o valor do id através do "inspecionar elemento" posso alterar ou deletar
qualquer registro no banco de dados. O que poderá causar um grande problema. Para deletar estou usando o JQuery e o méotodo $.post. Eu poderia
cifrar o valor do id e dificultar um pouco para quem quisesse burlar o sistema. Mas o que gostaria de saber é se existe uma maneira de se 
pegar o valor original no html e não o valor editado pelo "inspecionar elemento"?

Comment: O valor do "inspect element" é o valor do html, pois esse recurso do navegador permite alterar justamente o html, que é o que se vê. Você poderia passar o valor criptografado e/ou fazer uma verificação antes de executar a ação.

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade não é um problema, mas seria, se o usuário manipulasse o valor de `id="110"` e alterasse algum registro que não lhe é permitido alterar.

Supondo que o sistema só permita que o usuário edite as postagens proprietárias, o usuário **X** só pode alterar o próprio conteúdo `id="1" , id="2" , id="3"`. Se o usuário **X** manipular o input e tentar editar o `id="4"`, cabe ao sistema validar a ação e bloquear.

No mesmo gancho do exemplo acima, se o usuário **X** manipular o input entre os valores dos id's que são dele mesmo, não cabe ser interpretado como *erro*. Há N formas de se selecionar um id, pode ser via input select, radio, checkbox... Se não causa um acesso indevido, inspecionar elemento nada mais é que uma *'interface alternativa'*.

---

> Cabe a você ponderar se inspecionar elemento e mudar o id causaria um acesso indevido ou apenas selecionaria um item válido dentro de uma lista de opções aceitas.

<sub>Descreva mais o seu caso se possível. Poderemos auxilar melhor.</sub>

Comment: Eu tive o cuidado para exibir e  manipular os dados apenas para o usuário logado. O "manipulador" não teria a possibilidade de alterar ou excluir os dados de outro usuário. Mas neste este em especifico envolve produtos e movimentos fiscais. Então a exclusão de um registro poderia afetar a totalização, se o registro excluído não fizesse parte do movimento em exibição.

Comment: `"registro excluído não fizesse parte do movimento em exibição"` esse trecho me leva a crer que seu problema seja validação. Quais outras referências você está usando para garantir a ação?

Comment: Sim. Pode ser. Seu comentário me deu uma grande luz.. Na verdade resolveu o problema. Eu tenho uma entidade chamada movimento e associada a ela uma tabela chamada movimento_itens. Preciso garantir que quando alterar ou excluir um item, ele pertença ao movimento em questão. Se houver edição pelo inspetor, não haverá possibilidade de alteração de outros movimentos alheios. Obrigado!